# editing JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
obj = {key : val,
      key1 : val1,
      key2 : {key21 : val21,key22 : val22},
      key3 : val3}
```

I want to generate a new object to be like:

```
objnew = {key : val,
         key1 : val1,
         key21 : val21,
         key22 : val22,
         key3 : val3}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you stuck on? If you don't show effort, you won't get a lot of help.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments, if you *really* want to keep the order for whatever reason, and don't want to do it for anything but `key2`, here's a possible solution.

Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties/30919039) for information about order of object keys. In short, it's most likely a bad idea to rely on it in most cases. You'd be better off using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance or just an array.

```js
let obj = {
  key: 0,
  key1: 1,
  key2: {key21: 21, key22: 22},
  key3: 3
};

let objArray = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({key, value: obj[key]}));

let result = objArray.reduce((result, entry) => 
  Object.assign(result, entry.key === 'key2' ? entry.value : {[entry.key]: entry.value})
, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2-level object structure (with `Object.keys()` and `Object.assign()` functions):

```js
var obj = {
  'key' : 'val',
  'key1' : 'val1',
  'key2' : {'key21' : 'val21', 'key22' : 'val22'},
  'key3' : 'val3'
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
        Object.assign(obj, obj[k]);
        delete obj[k];
    }
});
  
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: this will push the new values at the end of the object. I need to keep it arranged.

Comment: also I just need to do this for key2 value not to apply this on the full object. just replace key2 by it's 2nd level object keys and valye

Comment: @amira, *I need to keep it arranged* - you can not, objects are unordered structures

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var obj = {
  key : 1,
  key1 : 2,
  key2 : { key21 : 3,key22 : 4 },
  key3 : 5
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
 if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(function(innerKey) {
      obj[innerKey] = obj[key][innerKey];
    });
    delete  obj[key];
  }
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: this will push the new values at the end of the object. I need to keep it arranged.
also, I just need to do this for key2 value not to apply this to the full object. just replace key2 by it's 2nd level object keys and value

Comment: @amira I think there is on way to order object properties in javascript. you can use an array if order is important to you.